# Distance similarity between two lists

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, distance

I am trying to find out the similarity score between two lists using L1 Norm. It should be between first array of first list and first array of second list, second array of first list and second array of second list and so on ( as I have a big list).
For example, two lists are as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

features1 = [array([0.02665389, 0.06815204, 0.14547031]), array([0, 0.00247839, 0.04664821, 0.5, 0.7]) ]
features2 = [array([0.02552605, 0.07776146, 0.18030827]), array([0.00000000e+00, 3.80687169e-03, 9.15574149e-02,0.5, 0.7])]
```

I'm not sure how I can compute the distance score, as the lists are unequal. I tried using numpy but I get broadcast error.

```
dist= np.max(np.sum(np.abs(np.subtract(features1,features2))))
print(dist)
```

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (5,)
```

Comment: What do the lists represent? If they are not equal in length, L1 is unusable. One cannot compute the similarity of two vectors describing entirely different things.

Comment: You could show the line you tried, but from the top of my head I would say you need to add `[0]` to both `features1` and `features2` inside.

Comment: Also, If you only need the two lists, please edit your question and make it simpler. There is no reason to introduce the features lists if you are only concerned with their two elements. That being said, it looks like they both *do have* length 3. So what gives? What did you try?

Comment: If your first sample is in m dim space, and second one in n dim space, i dont think a L1 norm would work as a similarity metric, but just to get some result, maybe you can compute L1 norm for MIN(m, n) dimensions of each sample.

For example
V1 = [1, 2, 3]
V2 = [2, 3, 4, 5]

compute L1 norm in MIN(3,4) dim 
L1Norm = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: @anuraagtummanapally But the comparison is only between equal arrays (3,) and (3,) from 1st and 2nd arrays

Comment: First arrays of lists only? Then `np.max(np.sum(np.abs(np.subtract(features1,features2))))` -> `np.max(np.sum(np.abs(np.subtract(features1[0],features2[0]))))` . And BTW, np.max is redundunt.

Comment: Continuation of my comment using the line you provided: `dist= np.max(np.sum(np.abs(np.subtract(features1[0],features2[0]))))` is what you could try.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

features1 = [array([0.02665389, 0.06815204, 0.14547031]), array([0, 0.00247839, 0.04664821, 0.5, 0.7]) ]
features2 = [array([0.02552605, 0.07776146, 0.18030827]), array([0.00000000e+00, 3.80687169e-03, 9.15574149e-02,0.5, 0.7])]

for i, elem in enumerate(features1):
    try:
        dist= np.max(np.sum(np.abs(np.subtract(features1[i],features2[i]))))
        print(dist)
    except:
        print("Lists might not be of identical length")
```